# How to create hundreds of copy of a label with different values in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to make 2000 labels with same design and numbering from 1001 to 2000. Manually its very time consuming. I know about the variables. but no idea about doing this on the same artboard. Please help.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: A bit more info would be useful. Are *all* the labels on the same artboard? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I need all on  the same artboard. what I have tried so far is load xml file and make action to save the file with the variables. Thats what I know. What I really want is to print maximum number of labels with different variables in a A4 sheet. Please help. Thanks in advance..

Comment: It would help if you could [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51837858/edit) your question with a list of what you've tried so far (so we don't suggest things you've already tried) and maybe a sample of your data.

Comment: First I designed the label.Then I selected a text where I want to put different values. Then I stored the values that I need to print on all the labels(for eg: 001,002,003...etc) in an xml file. Then I selected the load variable library from variable window in order to load the xml file into illustrator. Then I could create a action to save each label as each file. Then I made some preferences in batch option from the menu of action window. This is working. But I need to put the labels adjacent on the same art board.